# JanusGraph, Spark cluster failing to connect to Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, gremlin, janusgraph

I am trying to run a Spark job on a cluster that creates a JanusGraph.

I have an instance of JanusGraph server, Cassandra, ES running on a single machine, only the Spark computation occurs on the cluster. (Basically, I did a `janusgraph.sh start` on the machine

My configuration is as follows (x is the IP of the machine I am running the above instances on):

```
def getGraph(): JanusGraph = {
    val config = JanusGraphFactory.build()
    config.set("storage.backend", "cassandrathrift")
    config.set("storage.cassandrathrift.keyspace", "jgex")
    config.set("storage.hostname", "x")
    config.set("index.jgex.backend", "elasticsearch")
    config.set("index.jgex.index-name", "jgex")
    config.set("jgex.hostname", "x")
    config.open()
  }
```

But when I do a `spark-submit` of the fat jar on the cluster, I get this:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:69)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:477)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:409)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1376)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:164)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:133)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:123)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory$Builder.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:264)
    at janus_create$.getGraph(janus_create.scala:66)
    at janus_create$.makePropertiesandIndexes(janus_create.scala:830)
    at janus_create$.main(janus_create.scala:921)
    at janus_create.main(janus_create.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:627)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:58)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.getCassandraPartitioner(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:219)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.<init>(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:198)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeRawConnection(CTConnectionFactory.java:110)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeObject(CTConnectionFactory.java:74)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeObject(CTConnectionFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1179)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.getCassandraPartitioner(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:216)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
    ... 28 more
```

I tried switching between cassandra and cassandrathrift but both did not work. Also, where do I specify where my gremlin is running. Is that relevant?

Comment: Are you using the pre-packaged JanusGraph distribution for the single Cassandra node or are you using a standalone Cassandra node? And to clarify, you have a Spark cluster running on different machines than Cassandra/Elasticsearch/JanusGraph?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I had figured out what was going on, cassandra and ES were not responding to remote requests. I was running the pre-packaged JanusGraph distribution and yes, I have a Spark cluster running on different machines. 

Does setting up ES/Cassandra remotely need some special configuration? Also, how do I run multiple instances of Janusgraph server? Thanks.

Comment: I tried fixing a lot of things, I guess the sparse documentation related to this is making things a little more difficult than it should be. Janusgraph server is essentially a gremlin server and I can make conf changes to make the gremlin server point to the right cassandra and ES instances. But how do I configure my spark job to point to the right gremlin/janusgraph server? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prepackaged distribution assumes a single, localhost node of each Cassandra, Elasticsearch, and Gremlin Server. Notice the `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` at the bottom of your stack trace. If you have Spark running on a remote cluster, you need to ensure that the servers are available on a non-localhost address.

- Stop the distribution first with `bin/janusgraph.sh stop`
- Update the `listen_address` and `rpc_address` in `$JANUSGRAPH_HOME/conf/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` using the IP address of the machine ([Cassandra docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/config/configCassandra_yaml.html))
- Add `network.host` to `$JANUSGRAPH_HOME/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml` using the IP address of the machine ([Elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/network.host.html))
- Update the `host` in `$JANUSGRAPH_HOME/conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml` using the IP address of the machine ([JanusGraph docs](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/server.html))
- Assuming you are using the default Gremlin Server configuration `gremlin-server.yaml`, you need to update the properties file in `$JANUSGRAPH_HOME/conf/gremlin-server/janusgraph-cassandra-es-server.properties` using the IP address of the machine. Update `storage.hostname` and `index.search.hostname` using the IP address of the machine, matching the server settings above.

Update: It seems that there are errors in your graph connection properties that might be contributing to the problem:

- `config.set("storage.cassandrathrift.keyspace", "jgex")` -- should be `"storage.cassandra.keyspace"`
- `config.set("jgex.hostname", "x")` -- should be `"index.jgex.hostname"`

Comment: Thanks, I did everything you mentioned and now it's throwing a similar error, just for ElasticSearch.
Also, I wanted to ask, as far as I know, spark jobs should communicated with Gremlin server and they in turn should communicate with the backend/indexing backend. 
But in my spark code, I am needing to specify the location of cassandra and ES. So, how does the spark job know where my gremlin is? 
Do I need to specify it in my spark job?

Comment: Please see updated answer. Your code above is connecting directly to the storage backend and indexing backend, which is a valid approach. If you wanted to connect through the Gremlin Server, you would need to use a [Gremlin Driver](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.6/reference/#connecting-via-java) approach.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly!
Also, if I wanted to add a Array[Double] property, how do I define it in Scala?

`mgmt.makePropertyKey("prop1").dataType(classOf[java.util.Arrays]).make()` does not work.